# Pipe direct tty output to sed

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I have a script using for a building a program that I redirect to sed to highlight errors and such during the build.

This works great, but the problem is at the end of this build script it starts an application which usually writes to the terminal, but stdout and stderr redirection doesn't seem to capture it. I'm not exactly sure how this output gets printed and it's kind of complicated to figure out.

```
buildAndStartApp # everything outputs correctly
buildAndStartApp 2>&1 | colorize # Catches build output, but not server output
```

Is there any way to capture all terminal output? The "script" command catches everything, but I would like the output to still print to my terminal rather than redirecting to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out `script` has a -c option which runs a command and all of the output is printed to stdout as well as to a file.

My command ended up being:

```
script -c "buildAndStartApp" /dev/null | colorize
```

Answer (score 0):

First, when you use `script`, the output *does* still go to the terminal (as well as redirecting to the file).  You could do something like this in a second window to see the colorized output live:

```
tail -f typescript | colorize
```

Second, if the output of a command is going to the terminal even though you have both stdout and stderr redirected, it's possible that the command is writing directly to `/dev/tty`, in which case something like `script` that uses a pseudo-terminal is the only thing that will work.

Comment: I'd like to avoid tailing a file in a second window just to keep things simple and consistent with the rest of the build aliases I have set up. Is there any other pseudo-terminal options other than `script`?

Comment: Well, there's `screen`/`tmux`, which have command-line options for running a specific command and logging its output, but it would be a similar situation to `script` as far as logging to a file.