Issue with capturing full sftp log
I need to capture the full sftp log in a text file. I used the command
bash "$sftp_script" >> "$log_file" 2>&1;. But the line with the percentage completed is not written into the text file. How can I achieve this? My actual log look like below.
Connected to ftp.abc.com.
Changing to: /ftpdsp
sftp> put CUSTOM_DUP.TXT
Uploading CUSTOM_DUP.TXT to /ftpdsp/CUSTOM_DUP.TXT
CUSTOM_DUP_091024.TXT                                                                                                                100% 8294MB  28.7MB/s   04:48 
Connected to ftp.abc.com.
Changing to: /ftpdsp
sftp> put CUSTOM_DUP1.TXT
Uploading CUSTOM_DUP1.TXT to /ftpdsp/CUSTOM_DUP1.TXT
CUSTOM_DUP1_091024.TXT                                                                                                                100% 8072MB  29.5MB/s   04:50

Log written into text file is like below.
Connected to ftp.abc.com.
Changing to: /ftpdsp
sftp> put CUSTOM_DUP.TXT
Uploading CUSTOM_DUP.TXT to /ftpdsp/CUSTOM_DUP.TXT
Connected to ftp.abc.com.
Changing to: /ftpdsp
sftp> put CUSTOM_DUP1.TXT
Uploading CUSTOM_DUP1.TXT to /ftpdsp/CUSTOM_DUP1.TXT

Thanks in advance!!

Not really a programming question. In general, many tools do not print progress output to non-terminal output. You would have to trick sftp into believing its output still goes to terminal. I believe that script can do that. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/27492904/850848

This is a pet peeve of mine - some caveats in posts here, here, here,  here, ... ftp was written as a CLI terminal tool, not really intended/designed for scripts. Use SCP, or Expect, or Perl, etc. Prod will thank you.

@PaulHodges The question is about sftp, not ftp.

The relevant principles are the same, just complicated a little more by the security. SFTP is even more bound to the expectation of a live user. script is a good suggestion for solving the question asked, but any ftp-based script likely has much better alternatives unless it's purely a convenience script that will "never" be used by automation.

@PaulHodges Imo, sftp in batch mode (-b) is particularly designed for scripting.

True, but that was introduced in... OpenSSH 6.3? late 2021? Might not be available everywhere. (Wish it had been around when I was doing this in the 90's.) Also, if I get a list of files, which failed? For sftp to exit with an error is good, but if I need to know which failed, it's easier (to me) to loop through and scp each, though not every script needs that granularity. YMMV. Basically, I just wanted to point out some considerations, in case they mattered. Sorry if I overdo the wall-o-text. :)

@PaulHodges According to change log, the -b switch was introduced in 2001.

Figures. Not long after I stopped using it entirely, lol
